# How to deploy Nuxt on a VPS with VestaCP?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vps, vesta

I tried for days to deploy Nuxt in vesta, everytime the reverse nginx doesn't work, the port 3000 never opens on the server.

Comment: i have wrote an blog about it https://blogxon.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxt-on-a-vps

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the 3000 port is not open or available in your server so you can change the port to another one (like port 80 )

to change it follow the link bellow

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/